# Multiple formats in logging.properties

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I have two handlers in my logging.properties:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

Both use the `SimpleFormatter`:

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

But now I want two different formats for these handlers. The console handler should print only a short message. The file handler on the other hand should print a more detailed message.
But how to use different formats for both formatters? The following did not work:

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter.format = ...
```

And using

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format
```

below the corresonding formatters did not work either. Any ideas? I don't want to implement own formatters just as a workaround...

Comment: Implementing your own formatter is not a workaround. It is the proper way to implement the format you want.

Comment: Yes, but I can specify the format I want with the SimpleFormatter. So why should I develop an own formatter which basically does the same just to be able to configure the logger properly? That sound like a workaround to me.

Comment: If you specify a format for the SimpleFormatter, it will be taken by all instances of the SimpleFormatter. That is not what you want, right? You want a different one per handler. So, you can implement a formatter per format you require.

Comment: Basically I want the same (but not the identical) formatter - with different configurations. So I guess this is not possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: I see. Nevertheless: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter only supports one JVM wide format.  If your project includes [JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) 1.5.2 or later you can use the [CompactFormatter](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/util/logging/CompactFormatter.html#format-java.util.logging.LogRecord-) on your ConsoleHandler and the SimpleFormatter on your FileHandler.

```
##logging.properties#
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=com.sun.mail.util.logging.CompactFormatter
com.sun.mail.util.logging.CompactFormatter.format=%4$s: %5$s [%1$tc]%n
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tc %2$s%n%4$s: %5$s%6$s%n
```